# MySQL Query > Select future rows and check if specific column is filled AND matches variable > else take other column if it matches variable

Tags: mysql

How to query this structure:

```
// table
column1 | column2 | datetime_column
```

I´d like to pick each row (and all of it´s columns) which is not lying in the past and where its column1 is not null + its content matches $value. Only If column1 is null check if column2 content matches $value otherwise don´t pick row.

Here is what I´ve got:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime_column > NOW() AND ( column1 = "$value" OR column2 = "$value" )
```

of course this takes all rows where column1 or column2 matches $value. Could use a hint how to work with SQL if conditions.

Example (given that column1-2 are nullable)

```
// dynamic variable
$value = 'foo';

       column1 | column2 | datetime_column

row1 = foo     | bar     | 2013-12-01 10:00:00
row2 = NULL    | foo     | 2013-12-02 11:00:00
row3 = baz     | foo     | 2013-12-03 12:00:00
row4 = foo     | bar     | 2014-12-01 10:00:00
row5 = NULL    | foo     | 2014-12-02 11:00:00
row6 = baz     | foo     | 2014-12-03 12:00:00
```

fetched rows should be

```
row4 + row5
```

Comment: Perhaps your question would be clearer if you edited the question and included sample data and desired results.

Comment: So your goal is to return only _two_ columns from the query - _either_ (column1 or column2), and datetime_colum?

Comment: I made my question more precise ... hopefully :-)

Comment: You want to fetch the entire rows, containing all columns? Eg: {foo, bar, 2014-12-01 10:00:00} and {NULL, foo, 2014-12-02 11:00:00}? Still not clear...

Comment: Is $value still supposed to be 'test' in your example (or 'foo')? How does the date column effect the outcome (all of those rows are in the future)? Throw in a couple of past rows that also match one of your other conditions, please.

Comment: yes, I´d like to fetch entire rows - I adapted your comments in my question. Please have a look :-)

Comment: It appears that column1 being null is key to matching on column2. I've updated my answer with that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

  CREATE TABLE my_table
  (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
  ,column1 VARCHAR(12) NULL
  ,column2 VARCHAR(12) NULL
  ,datetime DATETIME NOT NULL
  );

  INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
  (1 ,'foo','bar','2013-12-01 10:00:00'),
  (2 , NULL,'foo','2013-12-02 11:00:00'),
  (3 ,'baz','foo','2013-12-03 12:00:00'),
  (4 ,'foo','bar','2014-12-01 10:00:00'),
  (5 , NULL,'foo','2014-12-02 11:00:00'),
  (6 ,'baz','foo','2014-12-03 12:00:00');

  SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 'foo' = COALESCE(column1,column2) AND datetime > NOW();
  +----+---------+---------+---------------------+
  | id | column1 | column2 | datetime            |
  +----+---------+---------+---------------------+
  |  4 | foo     | bar     | 2014-12-01 10:00:00 |
  |  5 | NULL    | foo     | 2014-12-02 11:00:00 |
  +----+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check out CASE.

```
SELECT 
   *,
   CASE
     WHEN column1 = "$value" THEN column1
     WHEN column2 = "$value" THEN column2
   END AS value
FROM table 
WHERE datetime_column > NOW() 
AND ( column1 = "$value" OR column2 = "$value" )
```

Ignore the asterix if you only want the value.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your need correctly (null matters for column1), I believe the following query will get what you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE datetime_column > NOW() AND (column1 = "$value" OR column1 is null AND column2 = "$value")
```

The above query says, "Give me rows from 'table' that are not in the past where column1 equals $value or where column1 has no value and column2 equals $value."

Comment: Removing the parenthesis will not improve the code, but simply produce the exact same result

Comment: It will change the filter. If "take" means the op only wants to retrieve a certain column based on conditions, then your answer is correct. I would've appreciated a clearer description from the op instead of a downvote by someone who thinks he understands better.

Comment: All right. It will change the filter. It depends on how you understand the question. Agreed to better description of the problem.

Comment: No problem. Some of this is guesswork when the op disappears for a while. ;-)